# Is it possible with Spring Boot to serve up JSPs with a JAR packaging?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm familiar with the Spring Boot [JSP sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp)

However that example uses the `WAR` packaging. Is it possible to do the same with `<packaging>JAR</packaging>`?

My goal is to put `JSP`s under `src/main/resources/jsp` to simplify the structure of my app.

Comment: The reason we put JSPs in WEB-INF is that it's protected.  Moving them out means that you would be able to access the JSP raw code using a browser.  This is bad from a security aspect.  However, I do believe you can do this.  You would have to configure your application's ViewResolver (This is a Spring class) to read your files from your /resources/jsp folder instead of from WEB-INF.

Comment: I had same problem so changed packaging to WAR and run as regular and it worked.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As @Andy Wilkinson said, there are limitations related to JSP. Please package your application as `war` and execute as `jar`. This is documented at spring site.

> With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work (...). **An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat**.

- [27.3.5 JSP limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)
- [jsp sample](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp)

---

*Deprecated, old answer*

Yes, this is possible with Spring Boot.

Take look at this example: https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-boot-web-jsp-example.

For doing this use [spring-boot-maven-plugin](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/README.html) or gradle equivalent.

With this plugin jar is executable and can serve JSP files.

```
$ mvn package
$ java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

(Note the extension of the artifact in the above command .war)
or just

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: When your application is packaged as an executable JAR file, there are some limitations with JSPs to be aware of: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot#jsp-limitations

Comment: @AndyWilkinson that link appears to have gone, is there an updated link?

Comment: @ben3000 http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: does not work. this example does not work. all pages 404

Comment: `Please package your application as war and execute as jar` - please update your answer to demonstrate this. Here I am interested executing the `war` as `jar` - links to specific instructions equally appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so i do have an executable war file working now. If using spring boot starter parent, just make packaging of type `war` and also reference `spring boot maven plugin` with configuration -> executable set to `true`

Comment: the github example worked for me when running from the command line. it did not work when running directly from the intellij spring boot run configuration. just fyi for others experiencing this problem

Comment: I did it: struts2 + tiles + jsp + tomcat embedded + docker
Took me 2 days, but I did.

Comment: I've 2 days trouble with jsp files in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp, did not worked for me,  but war package solved my problem.

Comment: I confirm that this solution (package as war and execute as jar) is indeed working.  In the process though I had to exclude from my dependencies (namely hbase-rest & hbase-client) a lot of old included versions.  So everything with `org.mortbay.jetty`, `javax.servlet`,  `javax.servlet.jsp`, `tomcat` was excluded from those 2 dependencies for errors to vanish and jsp pages to render. Running everything as Spring Boot 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT with Java 14. `mvn dependency:tree` is your best friend for this cleanup work.

Answer (score 7):

If your springboot is building your project  and running it in local server correctly then **YES**.
What you need to do is to build the project using 
    `mvn -U clean package`.
Then in  **target**  folder you have your runnable xxxx.jar . Now what you have to do is put your xxxx.jar file in the server or where you want along with the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` ***.jsp** files in same hierarchy.
    then try `java -jar xxxx.jar`
Your project will run with no issue.

```
`
.
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── webapp
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── jsp
│               │   ├── default.jsp
│               │   ├── help.jsp
│               │   ├── index.jsp
│               │   ├── insert.jsp
│               │   ├── login.jsp
│               │   ├── modify.jsp
│               │   ├── search.jsp
│               │   └── show.jsp
│               └── web.xml
├── xxx.jar
└── xxx.jar.original`
```

**java -jar xxx.jar**

```
<pre>    
$java -jar xxx.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-09-05 19:31:05.009  INFO 10325 --- [           main] com.myapp.app.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on dipu-HP with PID 10325 (/home/dipu/Documents/workspace-sts/jspjartest/xxx.jar started by dipu in /home/dipu/Documents/workspace-sts/jspjartest)
2017-09-05 19:31:05.014  INFO 10325 --- [           main] com.myapp.app.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-09-05 19:31:05.138  INFO 10325 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e5e91e4: startup date [Tue Sep 05 19:31:05 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-05 19:31:07.258  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2017-09-05 19:31:07.276  INFO 10325 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-09-05 19:31:07.278  INFO 10325 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-09-05 19:31:08.094  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-09-05 19:31:08.396  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-09-05 19:31:08.401  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3267 ms
2017-09-05 19:31:08.615  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-09-05 19:31:08.617  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'loginServlet' to [/loginServlet/]
2017-09-05 19:31:08.618  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'uploadController' to [/uploadController/]
2017-09-05 19:31:08.622  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-05 19:31:08.622  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-05 19:31:08.623  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-05 19:31:08.623  INFO 10325 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-05 19:31:09.137  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e5e91e4: startup date [Tue Sep 05 19:31:05 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-05 19:31:09.286  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user-management]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.user()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.288  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.reload()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.290  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/show]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.show()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.292  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/modify]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.modify()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.293  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/admin]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.admin()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.294  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.login()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.294  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/faq-management]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.faq()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.294  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/subject-area]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.subject()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.295  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Chat]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.index()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.295  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/delete]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.delete()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.296  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/result]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.result()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.296  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/insert]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.insert()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.300  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/fileUpload]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.file()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.301  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/search]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.search()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.301  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/help]}" onto java.lang.String com.myapp.app.DemoController.help()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.312  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/LoginServlet]}" onto public void com.myapp.app.LoginServlet.LoginServlet.doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.313  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/image],methods=[GET],produces=[text/html;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.ImageController.image()
2017-09-05 19:31:09.316  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/authenticate],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.authenticate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.317  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/searchCompany],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.getCompany(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.318  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/executeQuery],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.executeQuery(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.318  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/insertData],methods=[POST]}" onto public int com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.insertResources(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.319  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/showData],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.showResources(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.319  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/searchData],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.getSearchData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.319  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/deleteData],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.deleteData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.320  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/modifyData],methods=[POST]}" onto public int com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.modifyData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.322  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/suggestWords],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.suggestWords(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.322  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/authenticateUser],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.authenticateUser(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.323  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/insertJson],methods=[POST]}" onto public int com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.insertJsonResources(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.323  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/getvalue],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.getResource(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.324  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/searchQuery],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myapp.app.controller.AjaxController.getResources(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.330  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/upload],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.myapp.app.controller.UploadController.doPost(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException
2017-09-05 19:31:09.333  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-09-05 19:31:09.334  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-09-05 19:31:09.388  INFO 10325 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-05 19:31:09.388  INFO 10325 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-05 19:31:09.461  INFO 10325 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-05 19:31:09.752  INFO 10325 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-09-05 19:31:09.861  INFO 10325 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http)
2017-09-05 19:31:09.867  INFO 10325 --- [           main] com.myapp.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 5.349 seconds (JVM running for 5.866)

</pre>
```

**here the server is running**

`$ curl 127.0.0.1:8090/login
        Welcome to Login page`

**My POM.xml**

```
<code>
    

        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
         <artifactId>app</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <packaging>jar</packaging> 
         <name>Jsp Springboot</name>
         <description>Jsp Springboot</description> 
         <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
          <relativePath/> 
         </parent> 
         <properties>
          <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
          <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
          <java.version>1.8</java.version>
         </properties> 
         <dependencies>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          </dependency> 
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          </dependency> 
          
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency> 
          
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency> 
          
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency> 
          <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
           tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
           <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
           <version>4.6.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
           
          
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
           <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
           <version>3.3.7</version>
          </dependency>
          
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.16</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.16</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                <version>3.16</version>
            </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency> 
         </dependencies> 
         <build>
          <plugins>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
           </plugin> 
          
          </plugins>
         </build>
        </project>
    



    </code>
```

**my application.properties**

```
<code>
    spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
    server.port=8090
</code>
```

**My Project Structure**

```
<code>
.
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── myapp
│       │           └── app
│       │               ├── mynewapp
│       │               ├── controller
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── static
│       │       ├── assets
│       │       │   ├── css
│       │       │   │   ├── fonts
│       │       │   │   └── lib
│       │       │   ├── img
│       │       │   └── js
│       │       │       └── lib
│       │       ├── css
│       │       │   └── img
│       │       ├── fonts
│       │       ├── images
│       │       └── js
│       │           └── img
│       └── webapp
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── jsp
│               └── lib
</code>
```

**Thank You.**

Comment: Put src folder in target and run the jar with java -jar xxxx.jar.  Your project will serve jsp pages with no 404 error.

Comment: So that's why it worked locally when I was running `java -jar target/my-project.jar`! But this is not very convenient for a production deployment.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to change the packaging type into war, and it should work without further changes.

As mentioned in on of the comments above, there are some limitations:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: That's not a solution, the question relates to JAR's not WAR's

Comment: @Orby `java -jar my-project.war` works. It is only a problem if you really need your artifact name extension to be `.jar`.

Answer (score 5):

If for whatever reason, you can't deal with a war packaging, there's a hack. Full credit to [this](http://hengyunabc.github.io/spring-boot-fat-jar-jsp-sample/) guy for doing it for an older version of spring-boot.

One way to do this is to personalize tomcat and add `BOOT-INF/classes` to tomcat's ResourceSet. In tomcat, all scanned resources are put into something called a ResourceSet. For example, the META-INF/resources of the application jar package in the servlet 3.0 specification is scanned and put into the ResourceSet.

Now we need to find a way to add the BOOT-INF/classes directory of the fat jar to the ResourceSet. We can do this through the tomcat LifecycleListener interface, in the `Lifecycle.CONFIGURE_START_EVENT` event, get the BOOT-INF/classes URL, and then add this URL to the WebResourceSet. A complete example is [here](https://github.com/code4kix/spring-boot-examples), but you can do this like so:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tomcat.staticResourceCustomizer.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class TomcatConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<WebServerFactory> staticResourceCustomizer() {
        return new WebServerFactoryCustomizer<WebServerFactory>() {

        @Override
        public void customize(WebServerFactory factory) {
            if (factory instanceof TomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
                ((TomcatServletWebServerFactory) factory)
                        .addContextCustomizers(new org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatContextCustomizer() {
                            @Override
                            public void customize(Context context) {
                                context.addLifecycleListener(new StaticResourceConfigurer(context));
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then use the LifecycleListener like so:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot.ResourceSetType;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

public class StaticResourceConfigurer implements LifecycleListener {

    private final Context context;

    StaticResourceConfigurer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
        if (event.getType().equals(Lifecycle.CONFIGURE_START_EVENT)) {
            URL location = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

            if (ResourceUtils.isFileURL(location)) {
                // when run as exploded directory
                String rootFile = location.getFile();
                if (rootFile.endsWith("/BOOT-INF/classes/")) {
                    rootFile = rootFile.substring(0, rootFile.length() - "/BOOT-INF/classes/".length() + 1);
                }
                if (!new File(rootFile, "META-INF" + File.separator + "resources").isDirectory()) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    location = new File(rootFile).toURI().toURL();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can not add tomcat resources", e);
                }
            }

            String locationStr = location.toString();
            if (locationStr.endsWith("/BOOT-INF/classes!/")) {
                // when run as fat jar
                locationStr = locationStr.substring(0, locationStr.length() - "/BOOT-INF/classes!/".length() + 1);
                try {
                    location = new URL(locationStr);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can not add tomcat resources", e);
                }
            }
            this.context.getResources().createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/", location,
                    "/META-INF/resources");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> 27.3.5 JSP limitations
>
> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet
>   container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some
>   limitations in the JSP support.
>
> With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an
>   executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard
>   container (not limited to, but including Tomcat).
>
> An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern
>   in Tomcat.
>
> With Jetty it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable
>   war will work, and will also be deployable to any standard container.
>
> Undertow does not support JSPs.
>
> Creating a custom error.jsp page won’t override the default view for
>   error handling, custom error pages should be used instead.

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot is pretty good with JSP and it's little easy also just you need below configuration

1 - tomcat-embad-jasper dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2 - Add below configuration is application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

That's it still have some doubt then check it out below link

[Spring Boot and JSP integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3iy9XHwGQA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **JS**P successfully on **Spring Boot** Application with **jar packaging**, putting my JSP files on src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/JSP directory and configuring my Application as bellow

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/JSP/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

My Controller is:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/hello**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Example");
        model.addObject("message", "This is Hello World!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        System.out.println("° ° ° ° welcomePage running. model = " + model);
        return model;
    }
    . . .
```

And my hello.jsp is

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>   
    <h1>${message}</h1>
    <h2>Options: 
        <a href="<c:url value="/hello" />" >Home</a> | 
        <a href="<c:url value="/admin" />" >Administration</a> | 
        <a href="<c:url value="/super" />" >Super user</a>
        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}"> |
            <a href="<c:url value="/logout" />" >Logout</a> 
        </c:if>
    </h2>   
</body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml file is

```
<groupId>br.com.joao-parana</groupId>
<artifactId>my-spring-boot-app</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>my-spring-boot-app Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    . . . 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>my-spring-boot-app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I hope this help someone !

Comment: how are you running your app? Can you successfully run it with `java -jar your_app.jar`?  Maybe the `WEB-INF` directory is missing in executable jar file?  You could still run it successfully using `mvn spring:boot` or running main application directly. But am interested whether you can run as executable jar file with the above.

Comment: this doesn't work if it's jar packaged (and that was the main issue discussed here)

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/**</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/**</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- must use 1.4.2 version -->
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason anybody still needs this in SB2+ we had to slightly adjust lifecycleEvent method

```
@Override
public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
    if (event.getType().equals(Lifecycle.CONFIGURE_START_EVENT)) {
        URL location = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        if (new LocalDevelDetection().isDocker()){
            try {
                //This is necessary to make JSP work in docker --> not sure which of those mounts actually does the trick but I think /YOUR_SB_APP_NAME one works for docker-compose and the other one for "vanilla docker" (non-compose)
                context.getResources().createWebResourceSet(WebResourceRoot.ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/<<YOUR_SB_APP_NAME>>", new URL("jar:file:/<<PATH_TO_YOUR_SB_APP>>.jar!/"), "/META-INF/resources");
                context.getResources().createWebResourceSet(WebResourceRoot.ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/", new URL("jar:file:/<<PATH_TO_YOUR_SB_APP>>.jar!/"), "/META-INF/resources");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (ResourceUtils.isFileURL(location)) {
                // when run as exploded directory
                String rootFile = location.getFile();
                if (rootFile.endsWith("/BOOT-INF/classes/")) {
                    rootFile = rootFile.substring(0, rootFile.length() - "/BOOT-INF/classes/".length() + 1);
                }
                if (!new File(rootFile, "META-INF" + File.separator + "resources").isDirectory()) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    location = new File(rootFile).toURI()
                                                 .toURL();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can not add tomcat resources", e);
                }
            }

            String locationStr = location.toString();
            if (locationStr.endsWith("/BOOT-INF/classes!/")) {
                // when run as fat jar
                locationStr = locationStr.substring(0, locationStr.length() - "/BOOT-INF/classes!/".length() + 1);
                try {
                    location = new URL(locationStr);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can not add tomcat resources", e);
                }
            }
            this.context.getResources()
                        .createWebResourceSet(WebResourceRoot.ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/", location, "/META-INF/resources");
        }
    }
}
```

Oh and our LocalDevelDetection.isDocker() method:

```
public boolean isDocker(){
    try (Stream< String > stream =
            Files.lines(Paths.get("/proc/1/cgroup"))) {
        return stream.anyMatch(line -> line.contains("/docker"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figer out how to copy jsp's from jar to embedded tomcat folder

```
package com.demosoft.stlb.loadbalancer;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

@Component
public class JarFileResourcesExtractor implements ServletContextAware {

private String resourcePathPattern = "WEB-INF/**";
private String resourcePathPrefix = "WEB-INF/";
private String destination = "/WEB-INF/";
private ServletContext servletContext;
private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();



/**
 * Extracts the resource files found in the specified jar file into the destination path
 *
 * @throws IOException           If an IO error occurs when reading the jar file
 * @throws FileNotFoundException If the jar file cannot be found
 */
@PostConstruct
public void extractFiles() throws IOException {
    try {
        JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getContent();
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
        System.out.println("Tomcat destination : " + servletContext.getRealPath(destination));
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            processJarEntry(jarFile, entries);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find jar file in libs: ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("IOException while moving resources.", e);
    }
}

private void processJarEntry(JarFile jarFile, Enumeration<JarEntry> entries) throws IOException {
    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    if (pathMatcher.match(resourcePathPattern, entry.getName())) {
        String fileName = getFileName(entry);
        if (checkFileName(fileName)) return;
        String sourcePath = getSourcePath(entry, fileName);
        if (checkSourcePath(sourcePath)) return;
        copyAndClose(jarFile.getInputStream(entry), getOutputStream(fileName, sourcePath));

    }
}

private FileOutputStream getOutputStream(String fileName, String sourcePath) throws IOException {
    File destinationFolder = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(destination)+sourcePath);
    destinationFolder.mkdirs();
    File materializedFile = new File(destinationFolder, fileName);
    materializedFile.createNewFile();
    return new FileOutputStream(materializedFile);
}

private boolean checkSourcePath(String sourcePath) {
    return sourcePath.startsWith(".idea");
}

private String getSourcePath(JarEntry entry, String fileName) {
    String sourcePath = entry.getName().replaceFirst(fileName, "");
    sourcePath = sourcePath.replaceFirst(resourcePathPrefix, "").trim();
    return sourcePath;
}

private boolean checkFileName(String fileName) {
    return fileName.trim().equals("");
}

private String getFileName(JarEntry entry) {
    return entry.getName().replaceFirst(".*\\/", "");
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}

public static int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

private static void copyAndClose(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
            out.write(b, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out all possible solution finally this helped me out.
Add the following dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
<!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the view resolver to application.properties file.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Once, we are done with above code, we will build our project, using maven commands and then execute as standalone jar using standard java’s jar execution command.

```sh
cd <TO_YOUR_PROJECT_DIR>
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
java -jar target/<YOUR_PROJECT_CREATED_JAR>
```

Comment: Try copying that jar file to some place else other than target folder and then run the application using java -jar. See what happens.