# Is it possible with Spring Boot to serve up JSPs with a stand alone JAR packaging

Tags: maven, jsp, spring-boot

I try to build Spring Boot with JSP to jar packaging. I build project and it works fine when I run it with this commands

**$ mvn package**

**$ java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

but when I go to target directory ($cd target) and try

**$java -jar mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

the application runs fine but when I open browser and try to open the page I get error "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp"

I found this question, but when I try it I met the same problem
[Is it possible with Spring Boot to serve up JSPs with a JAR packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243690/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packaging/21244397#21244397?newreg=efcc11ff748f47caae3a583c0b26aa0c)

My questions is Why it works when I try

**$ java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

and doesn't work when I try

**$cd target**

**$java -jar mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

How can I solve it?

**EDIT**

There is not WEB-INF directory into jar or target directory and when I put it there it doesn't help

Comment: You cannot... See [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations). *"An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat."* from that same reference guide. You have to use `war` packaging to have it working reliably

Comment: I didn't notice it before it helps, but I still have the question why it works when I run "$ java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" and doen't works correctly when I run "$java -jar mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" from target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using embedded Tomcat, Spring Boot [doesn't support using JSPs in an executable jar](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations):

> With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.

It works when you try `java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` because the JSPs are available on the filesystem from `src/main/webapp` which Spring Boot configures as a document root for convenience during development. When you move into the target directory, the `src/main/webapp` folder is no longer available so the JSPs stop working.