# Spring Boot 1.3 : error on init.d service but "java -jar" working

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have an app that runs properly when I execute `java -jar myapp.jar` but when I link it to run as process I'm getting 404 error. So I made an gitHub repository only with the relevant classes to show you the error. Could you try to reproduce it?

Here is the code 
https://github.com/alephlm/spring-boot-1.3-error-executable-service

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this is a variant of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206862/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-stand-alone-jar-packagin/37211666#37211666

Answer (score 0):

Your maven script never explicitly packages the `webapp` contents, and even if it did, [Tomcat will not pick it up](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations). But, there is a work around, do the following:

- create a `META-INF/resources` in your resources folder (e.g. src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/)
- now move everything from under `webapp` to your new META-INF/resources folder (e.g. ..META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp)

I recently [read about it on Gunnar's blog](http://hillert.blogspot.com/2016/03/spring-boot-with-jsp-in-executable-jar.html). The great thing about this solution is that you don't have to mess with the maven copying resources, it will automatically get picked up since it's in src/main/resources.