# Why spring boot 1.5.3 jar does not recognise jsp files in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I used spring boot + jsp, and I want to build a executable jar, as [this post](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic/) pointed out,  just need put jsp files into `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/`.

> Fortunately we have another option for a Jar project: Servlet 3.0 specification allows to have dynamic pages in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/

But unfortunately I cannot access jsp page successfully. After trying every manner for a long time finally I decided to change `spring-boot-starter-web 1.5.3.RELEASE` to `1.4.2.RELEASE` as same  as this post demo, this time it works.

So why sprint boot 1.5.3 does not support put jsp files in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/`?

Comment: Just to be _clear_, if you follow the post, it tells you to put the views in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/*WEB-INF/views*` AND setting `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp`. Have you done that? Or you just placed the jsp files in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`?

Comment: Of course I know these  things. You could download the demo and just modify the spring boot version to prove it

Comment: That is a limitation of using JSP with an embedded container. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations. What you describe (and link to) is the default when deploying applications, as a war, to an servlet container.

Comment: For Spring Boot 2 see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50846032/1634131 Worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tracing source code I find why 1.5.3 cannot recognise jsp files.

`Spring boot 1.4.2`

```
//org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.StoreMergedWebXmlListener#onStart
private void onStart(Context context) {
    ServletContext servletContext = context.getServletContext();
    if(servletContext.getAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.MergedWebXml") == null) {
        servletContext.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.MergedWebXml", this.getEmptyWebXml());
    }

    TomcatResources.get(context).addClasspathResources(); // only 1.4.2 has this line 
}
```

`Spring boot 1.5.3`

```
    private void onStart(Context context) {
        ServletContext servletContext = context.getServletContext();
        if (servletContext.getAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML) == null) {
            servletContext.setAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML, getEmptyWebXml());
        }
    }
```

And how to let spring boot 1.5.3 also work as 1.4.2? Below is my manner:

1.copy source code of `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` to your class path
[image]

2.modify `onStart` method

```
private void onStart(Context context) {
    ServletContext servletContext = context.getServletContext();
    if (servletContext.getAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML) == null) {
        servletContext.setAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML, getEmptyWebXml());
    }
    // add below code    
    List<URL> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String file = "file:/Users/zhugw/workspace/boot-jar-serving-jsp/boot-jar-serving-jsp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/";
    try {
        URL jar = new URL("jar", null, file);
        list.add(jar);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TomcatResources.get(context).addResourceJars(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1.4.3 for spring-boot-maven-plugin the jsp files are not loaded anymore. To solve the problem use:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

You can find an example here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-exploded-war.html