# Having issue displaying JSP page in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I am having issue to display jsp page in Spring-MVC.
This is a basic *hello world* Spring-MVC with Gradle and IntelliJ CE:

I get the following error page:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.helloct'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'    

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")

    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")

    compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')    

    compile 'javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api'        

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

the The view resolver file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hello")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

The controller page:

```
@Controller
public class JSPController {
    @GetMapping("/jspPage")
    public String home(){
        return "jspPage";
    }
}
```

The [jsp page](https://hastebin.com/pinadumetu.js) location:

[image]

Content of the application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Using the default template engine, the page displays correctly but using jsp, it doesn't work

Log error:

https://hastebin.com/lijekesoti.apache

*NOTE: I know Thymleleaf is the recommanded template for Spring but I want work with JSP for some reason*

---

***UPDATE***

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169588/2056208) with the help of [paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53603984/2056208) answer, removing the following line:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

and removing the view resolver file solved my issue.

Comment: You forgot to show the most important information, i.e. the files inside the `views` folder. Is there a `jspPage.jsp` file there?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, there is a JSP file, just fixed the screenshot and added a link to its content.

Comment: Q: So what happened with this?  Did you resolve the problem?  Did my response help and/or correspond to your solution?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it's non-trivial to get JSPs to work with Spring Boot. It also turns out that there are significant changes between Spring Boot 1.x (which most of the tutorials for Spring Boot/JSP were written to) and Spring Boot 2.x.

I found these resources helpful:

- [Navin Reddy: Web App Using Spring Boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLbvzF1-vXY)
- [MKYong: Spring Boot Hello World Example – JSP](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)

I got JSP working with both Spring Boot 1.x and 2.x, with both Maven and Gradle.  My project is here on GitHub:

- https://github.com/paulsm4/HelloSpringBoot/tree/master/test7

These are the highlights of what I needed to do:

1. I created my starter project with Eclipse STS.

   It was important to specify "War" packaging (vs. the default "Jar")
2. I added the following dependencies in my `build.gradle`:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
     compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
     compile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api')
     compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
     compile('org.webjars:bootstrap:4.1.0')
     testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
   ```

   It turns out that 'tomcat-embedded' need *NOT* be specified (it's included in spring-boot-starter-web by default).

   But it also turns out that Embedded Tomcat won't process JSPs unless you explicitly include `tomcat-embed-jasper`.

   Don't specify a "thymeleaf" dependency - it will conflict with "jasper".
3. As per other tutorials, I added these lines in my `application.properties`:

   ```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
   ```

   I added also added these lines to my root class:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Test7Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
      ...  
      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
         return application.sources(Test7Application.class);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Test7Application.class, args);
      }
   ```
4. Unfortunately, "other tutorials" frequently say to create folder `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/`.  This will *NOT* work.

   Instead, I put my `test.jsp` file in folder `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp`.

   These links explain why:

   - [Spring Boot JSP 404](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383911/421195)
   - [Why spring boot 1.5.3 jar does not recognise jsp files in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689773)
5. At this point, I was successfully able to display both static and .jsp pages with Spring Boot.

I hope that helps!

Comment: 1. I Guess we were editing the post at the same time, so I delete your edit probably by accident. Feel free to edit it, I didn't want to include it as the post was already too long. Am not sure what you mean in 3.b and 3.c

Comment: If it's not already clear, then reading through the tutorials might help your better understand 3b and 3c.

Comment: Like can I put the JSP file in two different folders? "resources > static" and "webapp > jsp" ?

Comment: I think I did that, just used _views_ folder instead of _jsp_ folder. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, your folder is "webapps > WEB-INF > views".  I'm suggesting "webapps > views".  But more importantly, please scan through the links I cited (if you haven't already).

Comment: Well I did this because that's what people recommend, Even in your first link it's in WEB-INF. Same for the third link.

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessarily "the problem".  But FYI, "WEB-INF" is intended for things like descriptors (e.g. "web.xml"), lib/*.jar and client classes.  Static .html, .css, images and other artifacts are generally stored outside of WEB-INF.  Also FYI, I happen to use Eclipse (vs. IntelliJ), so I can't help if the problem turns out to be some kind of IDE-specific "gotcha".  Please keep us posted what you find!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184730/discussion-between-asme-just-and-paulsm4).

Comment: FYI, I bit the bullet ... created a new "Hello world" Spring Boot app in Eclipse ... enabled both Tomcat and Thymeleaf ... and I'm able to reproduce the problem: `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index.html]`.  Let me dig deeper to find a solution.

Comment: Hi, I finally got *ONE* example of Spring Boot + Embedded Tomcat/JSP working: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/.  You can download the working project and "readme.txt" [here](https://github.com/paulsm4/HelloSpringBoot), sub-project "spring-boot-web-jsp".  I'm still investigating other "variables" (e.g. Maven vs. Gradle, Spring Boot 1.x vs. Spring Boot 2.1.1, Windows vs. Linux, Thymeleaf vs. Tomcat-only, etc.).  As I investigate, I'll create Git branches for each "variable".  FYI - and I hope that helps you!

Comment: GOT IT!  The one final piece of "extra magic" I needed for Spring Boot 2.x/Gradle was to add this dependency to build.gradle: `compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')`!  I'll update my response - and post the complete project on Github.