# spring boot tomcat jsp is downloaded not rendered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am bootstrapping my spring application to spring boot and I have the problem that the embedded tomcat is not rendering the jsp files instead the file will be downloaded.

I have googled and tried everything what I have found so far but I still do anything wrong.

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Clipping from the application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Clipping from the Controller

```
    @GetMapping(value= "/")
public String showPage(Model theModel) {

    theModel.addAttribute("scrumbled", new Scrumbled());

    return "main";
}
```

What am I doing wrong that the jsp file is downloaded instead of showing and rendered in the browser?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is your folder structure. You have mentioned that spring.mvc.view.prefix=/ are the JSP's are in the mentioned path

Comment: Files are in the following location
'src/main/resources/META-INF/resources'
I also get the correct file but only as download.

Comment: Are you packaged as a JAR? There are limitations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243690/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packaging

Comment: At the moment yes. Packaged as a jar, but I also tried it with war with the exact same result.

Comment: Do you configured view resolver ? and put your jsp files inside of WEB-INF

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

The problem was a corrupted jar dependency. I had to maven clean, maven install the whole project to see the error. After deleting the jar from the file system maven downloaded the dependency again and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the jasper version. It worked with the below version irrespective of the tomcat version.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
     <version>9.0.24</version>`enter code here`
   </dependency>
```

My tomcat version was 9.0.63.