# spring boot maven doesn't package jsp files to "fat jar"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

i'm using project structure from guides, store css & js in static folder in resources and jsp files in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/

but when i build my spring boot application to fat jar by "maven package" task in eclipse it doesn't package all webapp folder to the jar

my project structure
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dADZt.png)

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.pa4ok</groupId>
    <artifactId>csplatform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>csplatform</name>
    <description>Remote studing web service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a "*JSP limitation*" in spring boot when done Jar packaging. In the official documentation it says as

> Do not use the src/main/webapp folder if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this folder is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.

[For more info read here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code)

So your webapp directory is getting ignored with fat jar packaging.

**One alternate** is to change the packaging to war and execute as how you execute a jar file.

**Other alternate** which could also work is to add the spring boot maven plugin with following.

```
<build>
     <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If either of them doesn't work for you, please follow this link to more [answers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243690/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packaging)