# Where does Spring Boot expect JSPs

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, jib

I did [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-jsp-view) tutorial to migrate an old jsp application to spring boot. But instead of maven i used gradle. In IntelliJ Idea everythings works as expceted.
Now i want to make a docker container of this application and therefore i used jib gradle plugin. But when i run this docker container i get an error "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp". And indeed the /WEB-INF/jsp directory is missing in the docker container. So i added it via jib extraDirectories parameter, but still it wasn't found. So where is Spring looking for this files? Where do i have to put my files? Is it possible to change this directory with a property?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) says

> #### JSP Limitations
>
> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet
> container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some
> limitations in the JSP support.
>
> - With Jetty and Tomcat, it should work if you use war packaging. ... JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar.

You can get more information in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243690/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packaging) too.

I looked into the tutorial link you provided, and I see the project packaging is `jar` and not `war`. Probably you'll need to convert your project to a `war` project by applying the Gradle WAR plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging i found out, that i could set the directory of jsp files by setting the document root of ServletWebServerFactory.

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

  @Value("${tomcat.server.document-root}")
  String documentRoot;

  @Bean
  public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    File documentRootFile = new File(documentRoot);
    tomcat.setDocumentRoot(documentRootFile);
    return tomcat;
  }
}
```

This solved the problem for me.