# Getting error from sprinng boot : Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring-boot

When I am  running this app from IDE, it is working fine, but when app running from the command line, it gives me the following error:

> http://localhost:8080/welcome
>
> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback. Thu Dec 30 21:46:01 BDT 2021 There was an
> unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

My controller is :

```java
package com.example.demo;

@Controller
public class HelloController {


    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("this is home page");

        return "home";
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Jsp file loction is :

webapp\views\home.jsp

Comment: What do you mean by 'app running from the command line'? `java -jar your-app.jar`?

Comment: java -jar spring-boot-ap.jar

Comment: With JSPs, you may be better off making a `war` instead of a `jar`... Have a look here: [is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packagin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243690/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packaging)

Comment: it works for me. can you check this repository ? https://github.com/joonseolee/basic-jsp