# Controller return string "login" instead of redirecting to "login.jsp" in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services

hello i am trying to build a web services for login page in springboot. When I run the project application all looks fine but problem is that instead of redirecting to "login.jsp" page controller return the string value "login". Any idea where i did wrong?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.micro</groupId>
<artifactId>login-mvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>login-mvc</name>
<description>a micro service for login</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application properties

```
##port
server.port=9001

##DB Connection
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

##MVC view
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Controller

```
package com.micro.services;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginController {
     @RequestMapping("/login-page")
     public String checkMVC() {
        return "login";
     }
}
```

SpringBootApplication :

```
package com.micro.services;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginMvcApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginMvcApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

login.jsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
    1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Login Page</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Friends I am learning WebServices!!!</h1>
    <div>
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <div><input type="text" name="userName" value=""></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="password" value=""></div>
            <div><input type="submit" name="login" value=""></div>
            <div><input type="button" name="Register" value=""></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
   <!--
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   -->
</body>
</html>
```

Project:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qejoA.png)

Browser:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txXyR.png)

Comment: You need to use @Controller for MVC. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation

Comment: @Mihail I got your point what you want to say. you just check the comment below what problem occured when i did that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController   <---------------
public class LoginController {
     @RequestMapping("/login-page")
     public String checkMVC() {
        return "login";
     }
```

The problem as I have marked in your code is that you have used `@RestController`, meaning it would parse the request and give back a response as the actual message body when you do `return "login"`. So in the body of response it is just written the String `"login"`.

What you need instead is `@Controller` which will work in context of Spring MVC, and when you do `return "login"`, it will by default search for a page with the name `login` to return, so it would translate your `login.jsp` into some html code and would return this page to the client as a response.

**Edit**: There is another problem with your project as well. As indicated by the [Spring boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations), when you package your application as jar, there are problems with rendering jsp views.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244397/7237884) to see how you can configure it to work.

Comment: hey @Panagiotis Bougioukos I have tried what you say to change `@RestController` to `Controller` but still it doesn't work and a `Whitelabel error page` Output i get. When i refresh my browser on console I get `2022-04-06 09:08:44.565  WARN 15324 --- [nio-9001-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound   : No mapping for GET /WEB-INF/login.jsp`

Comment: @VijayA76R check updated answer. Please don't forget to accept answer if it has solved your problem. You can always upvote as well :)